# Can we use if statement in linq for deciding to join or not?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I want to include a table in some conditions in Linq.

I am looking for sth like this:

```
var query = from x in context.Messages 
if(x.senderID != 0)
{
    join et in context.ETs on x.senderID equals et.ID
}
where x.Getter == SSN
select new { x.id, x.message}
```

Is this kind of approach possible or do I have to write two different linq queries and then I will combine them?

Comment: why not try left outer? i think it works with group join and using default values.

Comment: What do you want the result to be for items that *do* have a senderID of 0? Should they just not be in the results? If so, put a where clause before the join...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var query = from a in context.Messages
    join b in context.ETs
    on a.senderID equals b.ID
    into temp
    from b in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where a.Getter == SSN
    select new { a.id, a.message}
```